# Will and would for "has the capacity to"

Tags: will-would

[**Source**](http://hcot.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Longman_English_Grammar.pdf) (*Longman's English Grammar, 20th Edition 2003*)

page No 247

I've read in Longman English grammar.pdf that **will** and **would** can suggest 'has the capacity to' and would is more tentative than will-

For examples:

> That container will/won't hold a gallon. (definite)
>
> That container would/wouldn't hold a gallon. (tentative)

My questions:

1. In what kind of context the second example sentence fits best ?
2. How the second sentence with 'would' expresses tentativeness ?
3. Can't we just say "That container doesn't hold a gallon or That container holds a gallon without using will or would ?

Comment: Did you use your dictionary to learn what the adjective _tentative_ means?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure "would" can be used in the way you describe, because it implies a hypothetical, "If [A] happens, then [B] would be true."

> That container would hold a gallon (if you put a gallon in it).

I don't think this is more tentative (yes, meaning "expressing uncertainty") than "will".  It just implies that there's some hypothetical component to the sentence.  Consider these examples:

> Donald Trump will not be a great president.
>
> Donald Trump would not be a great president.

Whatever you may believe about the man, *at this point in time* the second sentence doesn't work because his presidency is no longer hypothetical. It would have been fine to say anytime up to November 9th, with the implied hypothetical "*if he becomes president*".

Meanwhile, before November 9th, you could have said the first sentence if you really believed he was going to become president -- i.e., that it wasn't a hypothetical.  But both are equally certain about him being a *bad* president.

Of course, you could also say "Donald Trump *is* a bad president" -- but that's kind of silly since he's not president yet.  Ask me again after January 20th, and I might be certain.

There are of course many ways to express uncertainty:

> That container *might* hold a gallon
>
> That container would *possibly* hold a gallon.
>
> That container *should* hold a gallon.
>
> Donald Trump will *likely* be a bad president.

And so on.

Comment: @Andraw It's not me Who described **would** in the way it is in the question but Longmanenglish grammar.pdf, Is it wrong description of the book?

Comment: @yubrajsharma I don't want to say someone else's lesson is *wrong*, but I can't think of any example to verify using *would* in a *tentative* manner (other than what is implied by the hypothetical). I'll think on it some more.